# How can i make the list form list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this

```
d = \
[('a', {'b': 'c1', 'd': 'f1'}),
 ('a', {'bb': 'c2', 'dd': 'f2'}),
 ('a', {'bbb': 'c3', 'ddd': 'f3'})]
```

I want the ouput like this

```
['c1', 'f1', 'f2', 'c2', 'c3', 'f3']
```

I have tried this

```
In [51]: [a.values() for k,a in d]
Out[51]: [['c1', 'f1'], ['f2', 'c2'], ['c3', 'f3']]
```

I want to do that simplest and shortest possible way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> d = \
[('a', {'b': 'c1', 'd': 'f1'}),
 ('a', {'bb': 'c2', 'dd': 'f2'}),
 ('a', {'bbb': 'c3', 'ddd': 'f3'})]
>>> [y for x in d for y in x[1].values()]
['c1', 'f1', 'f2', 'c2', 'c3', 'f3']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> d=[('a', {'b': 'c1', 'd': 'f1'}),
 ('a', {'bb': 'c2', 'dd': 'f2'}),
 ('a', {'bbb': 'c3', 'ddd': 'f3'})]

>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain.from_iterable( x[1].values() for x in d ))
['c1', 'f1', 'f2', 'c2', 'c3', 'f3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative answer using `reduce`:

```
import operator
reduce(operator.add,(a.values() for k,a in d))
```

Maybe not the best idea, but it works.  Essentially equivalent to Blender's

```
sum([a.values() for k, a in d], [])
```

Comment: I now understand why Guido removed `reduce` from builtins